# Whether and how to perform VIF and Condition Index on formative measurement model?

Tags: reliability, scales, variance-inflation-factor

I found this very interesting [paper](http://ro.uow.edu.au/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1003&context=sbshdr&sei-redir=1&referer=http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=8&ved=0CFcQFjAH&url=http%253A%252F%252Fro.uow.edu.au%252Fcgi%252Fviewcontent.cgi%253Farticle%253D1003%2526context%253Dsbshdr&rct=j&q=formative%2520model%2520reliability&ei=5q2NTvX8LoyZiAfun8DxBw&usg=AFQjCNFU_rXni4xkgWLRyszqnVNBQhwfGg&sig2=3Iul55bELUQg_ztUCUpl4g#search=%22formative%20model%20reliability%22) which I think provides some good guidance on testing the reliability of my **formative measurement model** - see earlier [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16578/how-to-assess-reliability-and-validity-of-composite-score-when-component-scales-h).

The relevant information is on page 6 of the paper and I am quoting it below (because I know external links are unstable and should not be used for ongoing reference):

**Extract from:**

Phatcharee Toghaw Thongrattana, "Assessing reliability and validity of a measurement instrument for studying uncertain factors in
Thai rice supply chain" (October 1, 2010). SBS HDR Student Conference. Paper 4.
http://ro.uow.edu.au/sbshdr/2010/papers/4

> *****Reliability test for Formative constructs***
>
> As formative constructs composited of different aspects of a
>   construct that their indicators are not necessary to correlate with
>   each other (Diamantopoulos and Winklhofer, 2001). Straub, Boudreau et
>   al. (2004, p.400) state that “it is not clear that reliability is a
>   concept that applies well to formative constructs”. This statement is
>   also supported by Diamantopoulos and Siguaw (2006, p.270) and Rossiter
>   (2002, p.315) that no dimensionality and reliability test are
>   performed on formative indicators because factorial unity in factor
>   analysis and internal consistency are not relevant. Although, low
>   item-to-total correlation should be dropped from measurement scales to
>   increase internal consistency reliability for reflective measurement
>   model because the scales are from the same content construct, the
>   removal of measurement scales in formative measurement model can lead
>   to change the empirical and conceptual meaning (MacKenzie et al.,
>   2005). Andreev, Heart et al. (2009) conclude that construct
>   reliability of formative should be performed by multicollinearity,
>   test of indicator validity (path coefficients significance), and
>   optionally, if appropriate, testretest (Petter et al., 2007).
>
> *On the other hand, reflective constructs that multicollinearity among
>   items in the same construct is desirable such as high Cronbach’s
>   alpha, but reliability of formative construct in term of
>   multicollinearity is not present because if multicollinearity is
>   present, it means that indicators are tapping into the same aspect of
>   the construct (Petter et al., 2007, p.641). Likewise, formative
>   measurement model is based on a multi-regression that
>   multicollinearity should not exist (Diamantopoulos and Winklhofer,
>   2001). Thus, reliability evaluation for formative constructs is to
>   assess the assumption of no multicollinearity (Diamantopoulos and
>   Siguaw, 2006). Variance Inflation Factor (VIF) is evaluated. There are
>   some guidelines that can be applied:
>
> • VIF is less than 3.3 that shows a excellent value (Diamantopoulos
>   and Siguaw, 2006). • VIF is less than 10 that no collinearity is
>   commonly accepted (Hair et al., 1995).
>
> As collinearity also can be harmful effects to formative constructs,
>   condition index is the standard diagnostics that measure the relative
>   amount of variance associated with an eigenvalue. Its threshold value
>   should be less than 30 to find no support for the existence of
>   collinearity (Hair et al., 1995). If multicollinearity exists, Petter,
>   Straub et al. (2007, p.642) recommended that at first, the model
>   construct may have both formative and reflective measures. Secondly,
>   the correlated measurement items can be removed, if content validity
>   is not affected. Thirdly, the correlated measurement items can be
>   collapsed into a composite index. Lastly, it can be converted into
>   multidimensional construct.

#### My questions

- How can I perform VIF and Condition Index using SPSS?
- Is VIF and Condition Index suitable for assessing reliability of formative constructs?

Comment: It is not quite clear what your questions is. Is it, "does it make sense to use VIF in assessing formative indicators?" (to which the answer is probably no, or with reservations -- it seems an odd measure to me, and it was designed for a different problem in mind), or "What is the button that I need to push in SPSS?" (in which case your kinda longish introduction is not that necessary). I would suggest taking a look at Bollen & Davis (SEM, 2009) and Bollen (2011 MISQ) for a different take. Given a less than perfect English of this student paper, I would have reservations advising to follow it.

Comment: VIF and condition index you can find in Linear Regression procedure. Under Options button select Collinearity diagnostics.

Comment: @StasK Thanks. I guess I also wanted to know if it make sense to use VIF in assessing formative measurement models but this did not come through in my question (my apology).

Comment: I've updated the question in light to incorporate both questions about implementation and correctness