# Dependent continuous and categorial predictors in logistic regression

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, categorical-data, multicollinearity

Given a set of variables (continuous and factors with more than two levels) I would like to show that one continuous variable (age) correlates in a certain sense with the professional status (a factor with levels: clerk, worker, retired and other). The target is credit default as indicator.

I think it is misleading to have both age and the prof.status in the model as retired and age are strongly related. Age is not related to the other classes.

If the professional_status were a continuous varible then correlation could show that one should not have both variables in the model. 
I have the impression that age and the status retired compensate each other in a similar way as correlated continuous variables would

What are statistical approaches that

1. a continuous variable and a factor (with more than 2 levels) are in relation
2. that therefore a logistic regression should not contain both.

What I have tried:

1. I cut age in bins and looked at default reates grouped by age bins times work satus
2. Regressions of Default on age and work satus w/o interaction: the coefficient of the indicator for "retired" loses significance.
3. and with interaction term: hard to describe :) $age * retired$ is significant on a 10% level.

Comment: Your title is confusing because it contradicts itself.  (By definition, the dependent variable in logistic regression is *binary*.)  Do you perhaps mean *independent* variables?  If so, one of the main points of logistic regression (or any multiple regression procedure, for that matter) is to handle independent variables that might be correlated, so what is the matter?

Comment: @whuber I mean the model is $Z \sim X + Y$ and $X$ and $Y$ are dependent. $X$ is continuous (age) and $Y$ a factor with 4 levels (status: retired, working, ...)

Comment: @Richard: 1) Better to reserve the term `dependent` to refer only to a `dependent variable` (`target variable`). The use of `dependent` to refer to independent variables that are `correlated` makes understanding your post and your comments very difficult. 2) How can `retirement` be considered a `professional status`? Retirement doesn't deprive one of his/her profession.

Comment: @AyalewA. I changed the titel to predictor, thus shoul be clear. And as correlation is rather reserved for coninuous random variables I don't want to use it for the description of the dependence between the categorical and the continuous. Your point 2 does not help to solve my question, does it? Of course your financial situation is different if you are active or if you are retired. And I can't change the risk factors I am given. These are the predictors.

Comment: @Richard Though your two predictors are correlated they are not completely redundant. Thus, you could do logistic regression and carry out collinearity diagnostics to see if collinearity is something to worry about. Looking at the following post may help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48688/multicollinearity-between-categorical-and-continuous-variable