# What's the reason for large beta coefficient standard error and estimate in binary logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, standard-error, separation

I'm using SPSS for binary logistic regression. The result showed that one of the variables has a large beta coefficient and standard error.

Here are some results:

[image]

Can some explain to me what is the reason for that?

additional info: the variable that have large beta coefficient and standard error are actually part of the categorical of age (i.e. age were being divided into 4 categories (e.g. 20-25, 26-30 etc). So in this regression binary is being used for 3 of the categories and 1 become the reference.

Comment: Are all your variables standardized? Otherwise we can't really say anything about the scale of the coefficient estimates without further details.

Comment: You should post (much) more details, but also search this site for Hauck Donner.

Comment: Or if you cannot understand the answers for Hauck Donner as @kjetilbhalvorsen suggested try searching for separation

Comment: additional info: the variable that have large beta coefficient and standard error are actually part of the categorical of age (i.e. age were being divided into 4 categories (e.g. 20-25, 26-30 etc). So in this regression binary is being used for 3 of the categories and 1 become the reference.

Comment: Have you followed up on either my suggestion or that of @kjetilbhalvorsen

Comment: So show us a table of the response variable versus the age categories?

Comment: Additional info should be added as an edit to the post, please!  And, you should not divide age into categories keep it as continuous and maybe represent it with a spline so the effect do not need be linear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enormous coefficients in logistic regression - what does it mean and what to do?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48739/enormous-coefficients-in-logistic-regression-what-does-it-mean-and-what-to-do)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has been asked for details and has not supplied them.